# wamp not working with php version 5.6.16 but it work for php version 7.0.0

Tags: windows-7, php, wamp

I am using wamp on windows-7, it was working fine with php version 5.6.16 previously But for some reason I changed php version to 7.0.0 it is working fine with php 7.0.0, but I need to reactive 5.6.16 php version in wamp but when I do this wamp is not working, wamp is orange and 1 of 2 services running.

Comment: Are you using the wampmanager menus to switch between versions of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding on `wamp is orange and 1 of 2 services running`, your apache service won't be running.

You need to reinstall wamp with php 5.6 after backing up your databases and `www/` directory and uninstalling the current version with PHP 7.

Things should work fine then.

Comment: It was working fine previously. How can I find error . There is no any information in Apache error log